# GAMS: How to solve for initial function value too large?

Tags: bounds, largenumber, gams-math

In GAMS, I get the following error message if I increase a parameter above a certain threshold:

** An initial function value is too large (larger than 1.0E+10).
    Scale the variables and/or equations or add bounds.

Is there a way I can get GAMS to tell me which value gets too large?

I am using a NLP model